# Solution to underdetermined linear equations

Tags: linear-algebra

I have a set of numbers $x_i$ and I know sums of certain subsets $y_i=\sum x_{\sigma_k}$. All $x_i>0$ and I'm looking for a simple solution.

With some internet research I found that this might be related to problems in signal processing. So basically I have given a vector $\mathbf{y}$ and a matrix $\mathbf{A}$ with $y_i>0$ and $A_{ij}\in\{0,1\}$. I'm looking for a solution to the vector $\mathbf{x}$ ($x_i\geq 0$) with

$\mathbf{A}\mathbf{x}=\mathbf{y}$

where this linear equation is *underdetermined*.

Apparently to complete this problem several norms to minimize on $\mathbf{x}$ are possible. For my particular task it's not clear whether I need L0, L1 or L2 norm, so any solution will do - as long as it's simple. Approximate solution like iterative approaches are also fine.

Can you suggest a way to solve this problem?
I'm looking for a reference to an algorithm which I can understand as a non-mathematician. Even better would be an open source implementation that I can download. And it would be perfect if it were a Python solution.

Comment: Hey! From the way you stated your question, it is not obvious how it's related to signal processing, and why it would be interesting to the community. If you can provide context that puts it in to the signal processing field, we'll be glad to help.

Comment: So, you want to minimize x, subject to the constraints Ax=y (equality constraint) and x >= 0 (inequality constraint). Is that correct? I think that's called a "quadratic programming" problem. I don't know a Python implementation of QP, though. Maybe you can solve it using the scipy.optimize.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Time warp to 2018 in case it helps the next person...

It sounds like you were trying to solve the underdetermined system of equations
$Ax=y$ subject to the constraint $x\geq0$. As you mentioned, this cannot be solved eactly so you have to minimise the [p-norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norm_(mathematics)#p-norm) of $||Ax-y||_p$ where $p$ is some number. The Euclidean norm ($p=2$) is the simplest way to go. You can formulate your problem as a *positive semidefinite [quadratic programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_programming) problem subject to box constraints*. There are many specialised solvers out there that can help you with this problem.

To formulate:
$$\text{min }\space\space f(x)=||Ax-y||_2\space\space\space \text{  s.t. }\space x\geq0$$

$$\begin{align*}
f(x)=||Ax-y||_2 
&=x^TA^TAx-2y^TAx+\text{const.} \\
&=\frac{1}{2}x^T(2A^TA)x+(-2y^TA)x+\text{const.} \\
&=\frac{1}{2}x^TQx+c^Tx+\text{const.}
\end{align*}$$

with the obvious substitutions for $Q$ and $c$ (ignore the constant). Clearly, if this was unconstrained, we could solve it in the way others have mentioned.
$$\nabla f(x^*)=0=2A^TAx^*-2A^Ty\implies A^TAx^*=A^Ty$$

However, you have inequality constraints so you cannot proceed analytically. Instead, you should use a quadratic programming solver to find the optimal solution.

There is a potential pitfall here. You mentioned that your problem was underdetermined. That is, your matrix $A$ has more columns than rows. In that case, your matrix $Q=2A^TA$ will be positive semi-definite but not positive definite. Many solvers will require $Q$ to be positive definite (as they will assume that $Q$ can be factorised via Cholesky decomposition). In English, what this means is that your underdetermined system may have many solutions and a lot of solvers expect there to be a unique solution.

Therefore, you should find a solver that can handle positive semidefinite $Q$ matrices or employ the standard trick of slightly perturbing $Q$ such that it becomes positive definite. That is

$$Q\rightarrow \tilde{Q}=Q+\epsilon \mathbb{1}$$

where you add a very small amount of the identity matrix to $Q$ to make it positive definite.

---

As you asked specifically about Python, there are [some excellent solvers for Python](https://scaron.info/blog/quadratic-programming-in-python.html) out there if you look. I like the `quadprog` solver which implements Goldfarb-Idnani's active set algorithm. It requires $Q$ to be PD so you will need to use the trick suggested above if you use `quadprog`.

Comment: Does that mean that usually a small perturbation is sufficient? What is a standard way to check whether a matrix is PD?

Comment: @Gerenuk in theory, $\epsilon$ can be arbitrarily small but, in practice, a very small perturbation could lead to numerical instabilities. A balance must be struck between stability and not changing the solution too much. Standard way to check pd? Check the diagonal is all positive and, if so, check whether the Cholesky factorisation succeeds. If it succeeds, it is PD. In the case above, however, the matrix $A$ will, at best achieve full row rank and so $Q$ cannot possibly achieve full rank. Hence, It will be positive semidefinite.

Answer (score 4):

You can solve the system in a least-squares sense:

$$\mathbf{Ax}=\mathbf{y}$$
$$\mathbf{A^{T}Ax}=\mathbf{A^{T}y}$$
$$\mathbf{Jx}=\mathbf{r}$$
$$\mathbf{x}=\mathbf{J^{-1}r}$$

where $\mathbf{J=A^{T}A}$ and $\mathbf{r=A^{T}y}$.

Note that $\mathbf{J^{-1}r=(\mathbf{A^{T}A)^{-1}A^{T}y}}$ which is application of left pseudoinverse of $\mathbf{A}$ - this obtain the least-squares solution in $\mathbf{x}$ if $\mathbf{A}$ is overdetermined or have full rank - but this may no be our case.

The $\mathbf{J}$ is $n\times n$ and is possibly rank-deficient (underdetermined solution).

The SVD of $\mathbf{J}$ is then

$$\mathbf{J}=USV^{T}$$

where

$U$ is $n\times n$ orthogonal.

$V$ is $n\times n$ orthogonal.

$S$ is $n\times n$ diagonal, with diagonal elements $\sigma_{1} \geq \sigma_{2} \geq \cdots \geq \sigma_{n} > 0$.

The solution of your linear system is given by

$$\mathbf{x}=\mathbf{J^{-1}r}=\left(USV^{T}\right)^{-1}=VS^{-1}U^{T}\mathbf{y}$$

or more specifically:

$$\mathbf{x}=\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{u_{i}^{T}\mathbf{r}}{\sigma_{i}}v_{i}$$

where $u_{i}\in \mathbb{R}^{m}$ and $v_{i}\in \mathbb{R}^{n}$ are *i*-th columns of $U$ and $V$, respectively.

We can extend the above sum for rank-deficient cases:

$$\mathbf{x}=\sum_{\sigma_{i}\neq 0}\frac{u_{i}^{T}\mathbf{r}}{\sigma_{i}}v_{i}+\sum_{\sigma_{i}=0}\tau_{i}v_{i}$$

where $\tau_{i}$ are arbitrary coefficients (any choice of $\tau_{i}$ satisfies your linear system).

It should be noted that by choosing $\tau_{i}=0$ yield minimum-norm solution, which is usually the most desirable one in undetermined and ill-conditioned systems (where singular values are almost zero).

**Source**: Nocedal, Wright: "Numerical Optimization, Second Edition", chapter 10.2 Linear Least-Squares Problems, p. 250

Comment: Is it correct to go to the $\mathbf{x}=\mathbf{A}^{-1}\mathbf{y}$ step? I'd think you can not write that since there doesn't exist a matrix that would cancel $\mathbf{A}$ at the $\mathbf{x}$.

Comment: Yes, the $\mathbf{A^{-1}}$ may not exist, but SVD of $\mathbf{A}$ always exists. When you take inverse of the SVD of $\mathbf{A}$, The $V$ and $U$ matrices are orthogonal and their inverses are guaranteed to exists, but $S^{-1}$ does not exists when $\mathbf{A}$ is not invertible (because of zero signular values - division by zero). The last formula in the answers deals with the zero signular values without explicitly computing the inverse. This allows you to get over the problem of non-invertible matrices. Another approach to undetermined systems is regularization.

Comment: I have updated the answer by adding a link to Wikipedia article showing the formula I have used in relation to regularization of ill-posed problems and the SVD. Hope it will help.

Comment: Yes, sure the SVD exists. But how do would proceed to get your equation $\mathbf{x}=\mathbf{A}^{-1}\mathbf{y}$ from my previous one? You would premuliply the inverse of that complete SVD to both sides. But that inverse doesnt exists. So you cannot say $\mathbf{A}^{-1}\mathbf{A}\mathbf{x}=\mathbf{x}$ for the left side, or can you?

Comment: $\mathbf{x}=\mathbf{A^{-1}y}$ is equivalent to your first equation and all the conditions for its solution are the same, so we can "afford" doing the step.

Comment: Maybe I am not right, so I picked up the book and updated my answer to put it more in context. Of course, if your original matrix $\mathbf{A}$ have less rows than columns, you can add rows filled with zeroes to have at least a square matrix and proceed with the solution provided in the answer.

Comment: Ah, I see. With adding the transpose it makes more sense :) Thanks. I need to look into it more closely, because I also need to incorperate the non-negativity conditions.

Answer (score -1):

If you have MATLAB simply use the "\" or "/" operator will do the trick. It solves the equation Ax = y in a least squared sense if it's under-determined. It determines the solution by solving |Ax-y|^2 = min. If you don't have Matlab you can do it manually by defining your error E = (Ax-y) * (Ax-y)' and then calculating the partial differentials dE/dyi setting them to zero. This give and system of linear equations that matches the number of elements and can therefore be solved using a regular linear equation solver.

Comment: It comes close, but I'm afraid it doesn't guarantee a positive solution.